# Show that $S:=\{x \in \Bbb R: 1 \leq x^3 \leq 2 \}$ is nonempty and bounded above. Let $a = \sup S$. Show $1 \leq a \leq 1.5$ and $a^ 3 = 2$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Define $S:=\{x \in \Bbb R \mid 1 \leq x^3 \leq 2 \}$.
a)Show that $S$ is nonempty and bounded above.
b)Let $a$ be the supremum of $S$. Show that $1 \leq a \leq 1.5$.
c)Show that $a^3 = 2$.
[You may assume without proof that $x \to x^3$ is an increasing function.]
For a, I showed that it's not empty, by showing that $1$ is in the set. I also showed its bounded above by doing this :
$x^3 \leq 2 $
$x \leq 2 ^{1/3}$
This concludes shows that $x$ is bounded above and that it's bounded above by $2^{1/3}$.
b) Assume $a$ is the supremum, then by definition $a$ needs to be the smallest upper bound and since we said $2^{1/3}$ is an upper bound, then $a \leq 2^{1/3} \leq 1.5$. thus, $a \leq 1.5$.  Also, by definition every single element in $S$ needs to be less than $a$, and since $1$ is in $S$, then $1 \leq a$.
c) i don't know how to proceed, I thought about doing contradiction and showing that $a^3$ cant be greater or less than $2$
In conclusion, i dont know if ive done part a and b correctly. Also, i have no idea how to do part C. i dont see how the fact that $x^3$ is increasing can help us. Can someone tell me how to improve the proof i have and how to have part  c.

Comment: Can you show that $(2^{1/3})^3=2$?

Comment: Copy of [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4626737/89922) that's deleted just now?

Comment: @peterwhy ye by accident I posted this in another account. this wasn't my intention. I wanted to post it on this one. I didn't realize.